# Reset radiobutton list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have created a custom control which has multiple type of controls like radiobutton list, dropdown list, textbox etc. I am using Control state to save the values. I am using jQuery to reset the values of all the controls in the custom control but the new values are not transferred to the controls.

I am calling the following function to reset the control in the custom control, but the values of the controls is not getting updated when I am saving the contents on button click.

```
function ResetControls() {
    $('div[id$=test]').each(function () {
        $(this).find('table').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("_ph_Test1") > 0) {
                $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
                    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
                        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                        $(this).change();
                    });
                    $(this).find('textarea').each(function () {
                        $(this).val('');
                        $(this).change();
                    });
                    $(this).find('select').each(function () {
                        $(this).val('');
                        $(this).change();
                    });
                    if (!$(this).is(':first-child')) {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

How can we update control state of controls using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: You would need to share some code

Comment: Please include your code with your question - both HTML and JS.

Comment: not clear. can you prepare a demo?